# Replacing sparse matrix inserting operation in Matlab by C++

Tags: c++, matlab, sparse-matrix, matlab-coder

I am using a optimization toolbox in Matlab R2016a. But it runs very slow. I find that the main reason is the sparse matrix indexing operation when the size of sparse matrix becomes more than 100000.

In a function of the toolbox, a sparse matrix `Jcon` is allocated space firstly .

```
Jcon = spalloc(nrows,ncols,nnonzeros);
```

Then some other code calculate something like derivatives. In the end some new enties are inserted into `Jcon` using the following code

```
Jcon(link_row(ii),col0Right) = DLink.x0_right(ii,jj);
```

`ii` and `jj` are loop variables. The right hand side is usually colume vactor with 4 to 30 rows. The size of `Jcon` may also change during the inserting operation.

How can I improve the inseting part? Is it possible to use C++ to replace the sparse matrix inserting? Will it be quiker?

Comment: Is it possible? Sure, C++ is turing complete so it can do anything.  Will it be faster?  Depends.

Comment: it will be faster since matlab is interpreting language, but  the performance boost might not be that big as u expect. Also, it depends on ur implementation (if u  implement it badly, it's might be even worse).

Comment: how dense is your sparse matrix? You could try replacing it with a dense matrix

Comment: Have you preallocated the space for the nonzero elements of the sparse matrix? Growing a sparse matrix is a very costly operation.

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure how dense it is. As it is a part of optimization toolbox, I may not be able to change the type of the variable. Sometimes the size of sparse matrix will be 2000 * 4000000, It takes too much time.

Comment: I think the toolbox preallocated it with `spalloc`, but in the later operation, the size may change.

Comment: Define your insert operation (a code snipped would be very useful). Are you inserting just a few non-zero entries at-a-time many times, or are you inserting thousands of entries at a time?

Comment: @dlasalle Inserting a few non-zeros entries (from 4 to 30 roughly) at-a-time for many times.

Comment: Are you performing operations on this matrix in between insertions (e.g., matrix multiplication)? If you add a code snippet/example, this will greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer.